# Java sphinx throws exception

Tags: java

I am working on Java sphinx speech, and i am getting the exception below while compiling the code. I never got any guidance to solve this exception. If anyone know, kindly guide me. Thanks.

> Property Exception component:'wordPruningLookaheadSearchManager'
>   property:'loader' - Attempt to set unregistered property

Comment: post your code at least...

Comment: Over 1,5k rep and ask such question?...

Answer (score 0):

you can put

```
try
{

///your code

}catch(e){

}
```

in catch you can show the reason of exeption with e .